# Cannot find ClientContext in Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll version 16.0.0.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013

I am trying to create object of ClientContext but Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll does not ClientContext definition. 
Any suggetions would be appreciated

using (Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext context = new Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext(sharePointSite))
                {
                }

Comment: *Have* you added the relevant dll? What is the compilation error? Does the compilation error mention that the dll may be missing?

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. It worked fine now after Removing the reference and adding latest reference.